# How do I get home sharing to work with iPad?

Tags: itunes, ipad, home-sharing

I can't seem to get home sharing to work with the iPad?  Does it not have this feature?

Comment: Do you mean Windows Home Group?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3819

> Home Sharing enables you to stream or transfer music, movies, TV shows, apps, and more among up to five authorized computers in your household. To do so, you will need to Turn on Home Sharing on each computer using the same Apple ID. Once set up, all the libraries from your computers you've enabled Home Sharing on will show up in the SHARED area of iTunes:

iOS 4.3 added home sharing functionality to the iPad, but you can only consume iTunes libraries shared by computers that have activated Home Sharing using the same Apple ID and only while iTunes is running. That is, while you can sign in to Home Sharing with an iPad, it doesn't share the iPad's library.

The content is accessed directly from the app where it will be "consumed". For example, in the video app a button in the library screen allows you to access shared library content.

Comment: I don't think this answer is accurate anymore.

Comment: @AdamWuerl How so...

Comment: Perhaps that's a little harsh, but when I read it I interpreted it to mean home sharing is an iTunes-only feature, but you can sign into a home sharing account with an iPad now.

Comment: @AdamWuerl My understanding is that while you can sign in to Home Sharing with an iPad, it doesn't share the library itself. You can only consume iTunes libraries. "Once set up, all the libraries from *your computers* you've enabled Home Sharing on..."

Answer (score 7):

iOS 4.3 introduces the ability to stream content from iTunes 10.2+ on your computer to your iPad, much like the second generation Apple TV.

To enable, go to your iPad Settings app, iPod setting category, and enter your username and password.  (the same info you entered in your iTunes Home Sharing setup menus). Also, make sure you're on the same network. Use wifi, not 3G on the iPad.

Then, in your iPod app, the "library" bar should now select **which** library.

However, I have not succeeded at this last step, despite many screenshots from the developer release showing what it should look like, and iTunes sharing working fine with my Apple TV

To accomplish the last step, simply tap the word library in you iPod app, and a pop up will allow you to select which library to access, including those shared on your home network.  To watch videos over the network just go to the Videos app, and you will see a new option in the top labeled Shared.  Tap it, and select the library you want access to, and you'll see all the videos available in that library.

Answer (score 1):

You can sync with an Apple TV easily. . . in Photos or in iPod.

- Set up your iPad with your home network per instructions.
- Configure your TV set for Apple TV.
- Turn on Apple TV with the remote Menu Button.
- Open Photos on your iPad.
- Select an album.
- On the top right of your screen you will see Slide Show . . . and an AirPlay logo, sort of a triangle pushing up through a box. Touch this AirPlay icon.
- You now have the option of viewing the slide show on your iPad screen or on your HD screen which is attach to your Apple TV. Select Apple TV.
- Either select Slide Show or navigate through the album by sliding your finger across the screen.

Virtually the same process is used to listen to music:

- Open iPod.
- To the left of the volume slider is the AirPlay logo. Select it and select Apple TV.
- The really neat thing now is that you can control the volume with the volume slider.

You can have a slide show and music streaming simultaneously.
Go to settings and select Photos or iPod to change preferences.