# Can I access mac iTunes library from an iPad?

Tags: macos, itunes, iphone, ipad

Can I access my iMac based iTunes library from my iPad over my home wifi?  I know I can sync them up but the library is too big.

Edit; just to clear(er), the movies, podcasts etc which are stored on the iMac, I want to watch them on my iPad without syncing. I know I can create playlist to sync a subset of my library, but that is not what I want.

What I'm thinking about is using my iPad as a kind of portable apple TV.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/145889/how-do-i-get-home-sharing-to-work-with-ipad

Comment: Not a dupe. This user probably wants the sound on his iPad also, which is not possible using home sharing alone.

Comment: A different solution to the "library too large to sync" problem is to create a smart playlist with criteria like "artist is not XXX" or "genre is not YYY" and set up your iPad so that it only syncs that playlist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried it on my iPhone, but it should be similar for iPad.

---

Download the *Remote* application from the iTunes/App Store.

Open it and enable *Home Sharing*, enter your Apple ID credentials. Open iTunes on your Mac, select *Advanced » Turn On Home Sharing*. Enter your Apple ID credentials there.

Now your iOS device can access your Mac's library and you can remotely control iTunes from your iOS device by using *Remote*. You can play the audio via the computer's speakers, or via any connected *AirTunes* speaker. Which the iPad is sadly not.

---

Get [Airfoil](http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/mac/) by Rogue Amoeba and the free companion app *Airfoil Speakers Touch* from the App Store.

Open *Airfoil Speakers Touch* to make your iOS device into a remote speaker for Airfoil. Start Airfoil on your Mac and select *System Audio* as the content to stream, and the destination *NameOfYouriPad*.

Switch back to *Remote* on your iOS device to control iTunes. As long as *Airfoil Speakers Touch* is running in the background, all audio from your computer is streamed to your iOS device.

---

If you want to stream video, [get Air Video](http://airvideoapp.com/).

Comment: Airfoil is btw available for Windows, so these steps should also apply to Windows based iTunes libraries.

Comment: I was hoping for a native apple solution, without going third-party. I just expected the apple devices to communicate better. However AirVideo look like exactly what I need, so I will try it out. Thx.

Comment: @Ken Doesn't exist (yet). There's a reason this application is popular.

Comment: I tried AirVideo, works great!

Answer (score 1):

Currently, you should be able to connect your iTunes to your iPad with Home Sharing, via the iPod/Music app on the iPad itself.

No 3rd party app is needed.

Comment: Please explain how that works... I thought you could only access music on the cloud (i.e. purchases from the iTunes store.)

Comment: The music should be needed inside your library. I'm pretty sure you need to turn on 'Home Sharing', both on iTunes, and your iDevice.