# Streaming video file to iPhone

Tags: macos, iphone, streaming

I have a http streaming link which gives me .flv streaming feed. I want to convert that and access in my iPhone program. How can i do that? I want to have a desktop software like VLC and input this streaming feed URL and convert to iPhone supported and stream again to iPhone. I tried VLC with H.264 and Mpeg-1 audio, but seems to be it doesn't give the supported format, so as iPhone program doesn't play the video.

Could someone please guide me how can i setup a desktop software which can stream iPhone supported file?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible out of the box. Only getting iTunes audio [is a bit complicated](https://superuser.com/questions/232250/can-i-access-mac-itunes-library-from-an-ipad).

Get [Air Video](http://www.inmethod.com/air-video/index.html) for what you want.

Comment: I am not expecting as Air Video which needs server and iphone to be installed.I want to develop my own program to play like Air Video iPhone app.So,i'm looking at VLC media player,which could able to set my flv based streaming url and give the encode settings supported for iPhone supported (H-264, MP3) and its able to start streaming the video.I am using Wifi and built-in Mac Apache web sharing is enabled,so my mac can act like a web server.But when i give my ip as http 192.168.0.103:8080, my iPhone program or Mac's quicktime doesn't play the stream video.What could be the reason?Pls advise.

Comment: @user You read the [wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:Streaming_HowTo/Streaming_for_the_iPhone)?

Comment: I already read and tried that, no success.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Serviio media Server on my Laptop to Stream many files to iPad and iPhone and TVs.
It has pretty much so many features. 
in the Application > Library tab > Online Sources
I can see there is an option to add EXTERNAL sources like "Live Stream", You can check that and see if this application can help you.

Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Answer (score -1):

There are two things, one is the video format, the other one is the transferring through iTunes.

As known, M4V is the supported video format for iTunes. Apart from iTunes, an iPhone user (you) can't download or transfer files directly from computer to iPhone. Thus, you need to do two things, one is to convert your .flv video. The other one is to find a program to transfer files from computer to your iPhone directly (But it often costs).